# Bash: extract the scheme and host part from a URL string

Tags: regex, bash

i need to strip the url from a given string.
The only solution i have is:

```
_url="http://download.enlightenment.org/rel/apps/econnman/econnman-1.1.tar.gz"
_l=${_url%.*/*}        #  http://download.enlightenment
_l=${#_l}              #  29
_url=${_url:0:${l}+4}  #  http://download.enlightenment.org
```

But this will fail on every none 3 chars length TLD and it's just the wrong way.

thx a lot.

Comment: bash only? Can you use awk or sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **extract a substring from a value already contained in a *shell variable*, use Bash's regex-matching operator, `=~`**, which supports extended regular expressions:

<sup>Note: [dawg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40454842/45375) contains solutions that are better suited to input from a *file* or *stdin* with *multiple* inputs.

They incur startup cost due to involving child processes, but for collections of inputs that is well worth it, because external utilities are much more efficient at processing larger input sets.</sup>

```
_url='http://download.enlightenment.org/rel/apps/econnman/econnman-1.1.tar.gz'
[[ $_url =~ ^https?://[^/]+ ]] && _url="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
echo "$_url"   # -> 'http://download.enlightenment.org'
```

- `^https?://[^/]+ ]]` matches any string that starts with (`^`) literal `http://` or `https://` and matches the longest nonempty (`+`) run of characters that follows that doesn't include `/` (`[^/]+`).
- Built-in array `BASH_REMATCH` contains the results of the most recent application of the `=~` operator, with the first element (with index `0`) containing whatever the regex matched as a whole.
  (Subsequent elements would contain what parenthesized
  *sub*-expressions (a.k.a capture groups) matched, but in this case we're not using any).

Comment: Works perfectly for my needs i only change it a little bit  
... ^http://[^/]+ ... to ... ^https*://[^/]+ ...
so i can use http and https.

Comment: @wfx: Glad to hear it; `^https?://[^/]+` is a little more robust, though - I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `grep`:

```
 $ echo "$_url" | grep -Eo '^http[s]?://[^/]+'
 http://download.enlightenment.org
```

You can use `expr` with a regex:

```
$ echo `expr "$_url" : '\(http://[^/]*\)'`
http://download.enlightenment.org
```

Or, use `awk`:

```
echo "$_url" | awk -F/ 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {print $1 OFS OFS $3}'
http://download.enlightenment.org
```

You can use `cut`:

```
echo "$_url" | cut -d/ -f1-3
http://download.enlightenment.org
```

`cut` is probably the easiest to get the rest of the url as well:

```
$ echo "$_url" | cut -d/ -f4-
rel/apps/econnman/econnman-1.1.tar.gz
```

---

Or, completely internal to Bash:

```
 $ [[ $_url =~ ^([^:]+://[^/]+)/?(.*)$ ]] && server="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
 $ echo "$server"
 http://download.enlightenment.org
```

and `"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"` has the rest of the url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works for bash, but it works for pcre regex engine.

```
(?<=:\/\/)(.*)(?=\/)
```

Finds all text between first `/` and second `/`. Works for `https://google.com/` but doesn't for `google.com/` or `https://google.com`. Depends on what you need.

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/mu3bk9/1)